# Assigning class from a specific tag

Tags: jquery, tags

Is it possible to modify the code below so each < li class=" "> has a class with the text from their first span tag?

```
    $("#tabs-2").one("click", function(){
    var x = $("#people span:first").text();
    $("#drinks li").addClass(x);
    });


   <ul id="people">
        <li id="singer">
            <span class="0">1</span>
            <span class="1">jane doe</span>
            <span class="2">F</span>
            </li>

        <li id="singer">
            <span class="0">2</span>
            <span class="1">john doe</span>
            <span class="2">m</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: note: you have multiple elements with the same id `signer`, id must be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#people').children().addClass(function(){
    return $(this).find('span:first').text()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mqscE/)